# Laravel: custom http status code not working

Tags: php, laravel, response, http-status-codes, custom-headers

> Laravel version: 5.5

I am trying to return custom http status code from the laravel controller. (Calling this url using jQuery Ajax $.get())

In my controller function I tried both the way mentioned bellow but it's not working.

1. This one returns error ***"Method setStatusCode does not exist."***

   ```
   return response()->setStatusCode(202);
   ```
2. This one not throwing error but returning 200 always.

   ```
   $response = new Response();
   $response->setStatusCode(202);
   $response->header('custom', 555);
   return $response;`
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Use it like this:

```
return response()->json("response content", 202);
//or
return response()->make("response content", 202);
```

Check https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.html for more detailed documentation.

Comment: I still wonders why not working. btw i am calling the http request from jQuery ajax. is there something to do with it?

Comment: response() function returns a response FACTORY not a response instance, so setStatusCode is not defined in a factory class. You need to create a response instance to set a status code. make and json functions do that.

And second option that you used fails probably because you are not using Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response class but some other Response class.

Comment: I was using `use Illuminate\Http\Response;` now using `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;` still returning the 200 with #2.

Comment: Guess what? i should delete this thread. all of your codes working. the reason was i was calling a internal function withing the controller public function and returning from the 2nd one. now i updated the code to return from the 2nd and the caller public function. it works. sorry. but this was not the issue so deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return response()->json(['hello' => $value],201);`

Comment: using `use Illuminate\Http\Response;` returns `message Method json does not exist.`

Comment: response()->json() should do it

Comment: Guess what? i should delete this thread. all of your codes working. the reason was i was calling a internal function withing the controller public function and returning from the 2nd one. now i updated the code to return from the 2nd and the caller public function. it works. sorry. but this was not the issue so deleting it.

Comment: Do not delete the question, it could be useful to people having the same issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let me present a few more methods of use. Maybe you are looking for something like this without json.

```
response(null)->setStatusCode(202);
response(null, 202);
```